System.IO.FileNotFoundException:Could't load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
I upgraded the existing Xamarin application to MAUI. I removed all libraries that depend on the Xamarin.Android.Support libraries. But still I'm facing below issue.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?


Did you use any other package that refers to the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat? You can try to update the packages's version in your project.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT No. I verified if any library depends on this library or not. But i didn't found any library that depends on this library.

If you migrate the project to .net 8, you can try to update all the packages to the last version.

@Chandramouli I would create empty project, and start adding packages one by one, until I get this error.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes upgraded all the libraries to latest version.

If so, you may need to try the way H.A.H said.

@H.A.H. Thank you. I found the culprit "Plugin.CustomCamera" with your suggestion.

Did you mean the Plugin.CustomCamera refer to Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat?

From what I see, Plugin.CustomCamera is Camera.MAUI, but for Xamarin. I would try to replace it.

By following @h.a.h suggestion in comments, I created an empty project, and started adding packages one by one, until I get this error.
The culprit "Plugin.CustomCamera".
